# Multiple database joins

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, join

I have three tables: `categories`, `content_info`, and `content`.

- The `categories` table contains the category's `id` and the ID of its `parent` category.
- The `content_info` contains two columns: `entry_id` for the post's ID and `cat_id` for the ID of the post's category.
- The `content` table contains multiple columns about the post - such as `ID`, `title`, etc.

I have a variable in the URL called parent_id which corresponds to the `parent` of a category.  I want to list all the POSTS (not CATEGORIES) which belong to a category with a `parent` of the parent_id value.

For example, say the parent_id value is 5.  Each post might belong to a category with an ID of 20, but that category belongs to the parent category (whose ID is 5). I want to list all the posts who belong to categories with a `parent` value of whatever the current parent_id happens to be.

Is there a way of doing this with MySQL joins instead of changing the PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT c.* FROM content
    JOIN content_info ci ON ci.entry_id=c.id
    JOIN categories cat ON cat.id=ci.cat_id
WHERE cat.parent_id=<parent_id>
```

This return all posts (`content` rows) which belong to a category which parent is `parent_id`

Or with subqueries:

```
SELECT c.* FROM content
JOIN content_info ci ON ci.entry_id=c.id
WHERE ci.cat_id IN (SELECT id 
                    FROM categories cat 
                    WHERE cat.parent_id=<parent_id>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM content c,
     categories cat,
     content_info ci
WHERE c.id = ci.entry_id
AND   cat.id = ci.cat_id
AND   cat.parent_id = 5
```