# does mysql supports inner and outer join when used in php

Tags: php, mysql

My project has more of filter things which will require join queries, nested queries to fetch the desired result,there are many filters so my worry is that does php supports these thing at large level because what i know is the MINUS query doesn't work in php(mysql). If anybody had experienced any problem in using joins? if yes then whats the solution??

Comment: What exactly is the MINUS query?

Comment: that set query union , intersect and minus...sorry couldn't explain it properly

Comment: In practice, whatever runs in the mysql command line client will work in PHP.

Comment: @anshu.insomniac As you've mentioned in comments you colleagues say that it will cause problems. What kind of problems? If you write awful code you may run in a very bad situation even with simple select query. BTW, any good/advanced ORM uses joins and they work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep, used several times without any problem

Comment: Are you sure buddy , coz many of my colleagues they are saying that it might coz problems when it will have to fetch larger amount of rows...

Comment: I'm sure, used it with large amount of data and it worked just fine :)

Comment: If you're working with reaaaally big amount of data, it's not even preferable to use MySQL alone, just use it with SOLR or something. Or even use MongoSQL. They are much better for scalability

Comment: I don't know what exactly large database is but all i can say is 13 tables after all kind of normalization have been formed and i guess number of rows after deployment would will be uncountable. So u tell me is it large enough to use MongoSQL

Comment: For 13 tables, I don't expect a large system with much scalability needed. But it also depends on the number of hits, your queries and the number of rows. You need a Senior SW Developer who knows all about your system to tell you if it needs scalability or not

Comment: I will talk about it actually before I was working on oracle with java and all of sudden I was instructed to work on mysql and php...thats why i am afraid and asking to much non-sense...thanks for helping if anything happens i will let you know

Answer (score 1):

Joins are related to Date Bases why they will create some issue with PHP, they will work fine... 
[reff for using joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897954/joining-tables-from-different-database)  also see [Multiple database joins for reff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845351/multiple-database-joins)

Comment: Thats what i thought initially but as my senior colleagues' advised i am li'l bit afraid

Comment: check the reff link, not answer of your problem but showing that you can use join in PHP

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with all the join types. I've worked with all the types and not faced any problem till now.